# t test getting nan output for both

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats

Every t test I run outputs nan for both statistic and p value
I have checked my dataframes and they look fine.
Does anyone know what's happening?
Thanks in advance!

```
e_tr.groupby('Rest Periods')['Wages and Hours'].mean()

#t test
cat1 = e_tr[e_tr['Rest Periods']==0]
cat2 = e_tr[e_tr['Rest Periods']==1]
# cat1['Wages and Hours'].value_counts()
sp.stats.ttest_ind(cat1.dropna()['Rest Periods'], cat2.dropna()['Rest Periods'])
ttest_ind(cat1['Wages and Hours'], cat2['Wages and Hours'])
```

Output: Ttest_indResult(statistic=nan, pvalue=nan)

Comment: The question is not fully transparent, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more information. E.g. what is `e_tr` here and what libraries you're using? It may only be obvious for you.

Answer (score 3):

That is possibly because your test and contro in column *'Wages and Hours'*  still contain `np.nan`. Try to clean your data first:

```
e_tr=e_tr[e_tr['Wages and Hours'].notnull()]
```

Then assign case and control as you did:

```
cat1 = e_tr[e_tr['Rest Periods']==0]
cat2 = e_tr[e_tr['Rest Periods']==1]
```

So now if you run:

```
ttest_ind(cat1['Wages and Hours'], cat2['Wages and Hours'])
```

Should give your the anticipated statistics.